# USB HUB buzzing noise when power connected to same charger as laptop

Tags: usb, laptop, power-supply, usb-hub

My laptop is powered using a 3rd party GaN charger which provide 2 more (typec-max65w, typea-max18w) charge ports for convenience. I have a usb3.1g2 hub connect to my laptop's dedicated type-C port. Since I have 3 external ssd connect to the hub, the power from laptop is not enough obviously. The hub has an external DC port as type-c to power the hub itself and it's child devices. I connect the dc port to my GaN charge using a A-C cable. The devices are working fine. But, every time I play game, the hub starting to produce buzzing nosie loudly. I tested the metal shielding of my laptop's and hub's male port. There's a 54 mV 40 mA current flowing through when I playing game. Ever worse, the noise will instantly happen if I just put both metal shielding together without plug the port in.

The charger is properly grounded. But I think my laptop's DC port only have 2 lanes as it is like the ports you normally see on routers.

Is there anyway to mitigate this? (Also I'm wondering the source of the problem)

It looks like this is confusing the attached devices,they stops responding after a while.

Any suggestion are welcome.

[image: connection]
[Question moved to SuperUser as suggested by https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110554]

Comment: "54 mV 40 mA" from where to where? How did you measure that? Putting probes on hub and and laptop ground would measure a *voltage* drop; how did you determine the *current*? Also, why would 0.054 V drop on a cable be significant? You can try reversing the laptops 2-wire plug, if it's not polarized.

Comment: I'm new comer to this. Yes I put the probe on both the laptop port shell and hub plug shell(when hub is Not plugged in the laptop yet).I tried both the V and A mode and the value is what you see. The value is where I'm playing game and the hub starting to buzzing, otherwise it's very low.

Comment: Values are safe.

Comment: I known the values are very small.The real problem is the buzzing noise and data interruption.    BTW,Should I try to cut all the ground wire of the plug cable?

Comment: Why would you *cut* the ground wire? It would destroy the cable. The issue is not a ground *loop*, but induced hum.

Comment: Thanks. I searched on google and found https://www.psaudio.com/blogs/how-to/how-to-find-and-fix-hum. I don't know what to now if it's not ground loop. I'm currrently power the hub using a mid power bank and it barely last for six hours. [Also I updated the post with the image of the connections if you haven't notice.]

Comment: So I tried powering the hub using a C2C cable with the TypeC charge port on the charger. Unfortunately,this does not give power to the hub somehow,The interesting thing is when I connect the data plug into my laptop(The c2c power cable is not unplugged yet),the hub powered up and my chager's led  turns red indicating there's current flowing into the charger..

Comment: I finnaly fixed this by making a custom c2c adaper that cut the ground line since it's not needed when hub is powered externally. The noise now gone. It seems the unneeded current wave is  generated by the laptop's GPU.

Answer (score 1):

I finally fixed this by making a custom c2c adapter that cut the ground line since it's not needed when hub is powered externally. The noise now gone. It seems the unneeded current wave is generated by the laptop's GPU and coming out to the shared ground.